# odoo ir.sequence not working when Use a user other than the system administrator

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I'm working on Openerp7
I try to convert attachments to files that are saved in the server instead of saving them in the database

My problem is in naming files
I'm trying to add a serial number to her name using ir.sequence

It works fine when I log in using the system administrator
But when logging in using any other user : ir.sequence not create the sequence
the Function create return False

my xml code:

```
    <record id="ir_attachment" model="ir.sequence.type">
        <field name="name">ir attachment</field>
        <field name="code">ir.attachment</field>
    </record>

    <record id="seq_ir_attachment" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">ir attachment</field>
        <field name="code">ir.attachment</field>
        <field name="prefix">Att</field>
        <field name="padding">5</field>
        <field name="implementation">no_gap</field>
    </record>
```

python code :

data_rec.write({'file_name':self.pool.get("ir.sequence").get(cr,uid,'ir.attachment')})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `get` method returns `False` because the `ir.attachment` company is not present in the currently visible companies and different from `False` (set to default value).

The `get` method will end by calling the [_next](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7.0/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_sequence.py#L237) method, which will return `False` if we provide an empty sequence ids list (`seq_ids`).

The sequence ids list (`ids`) is computed like following:

```py
company_ids = self.pool.get('res.company').search(cr, uid, [], context=context) + [False]
ids = self.search(cr, uid, ['&', ('code', '=', sequence_code), ('company_id', 'in', company_ids)])
```

It works fine when you log in using the system administrator because the superuser bypasses the security rules and can see all the available companies, but a user is able to select only the currently visible companies according to rules.

After selecting the visible companies of the current user, OpenERP adds `False` to that list ( which means that if the sequence `company_id` [is not set](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7.0/addons/sale/sale_sequence.xml#L16), the sequence id that corresponds to the code passed to the `search` method will always be returned without depending on the user settings) then, it will try to find the sequence ids where sequence code is equal to the sequence code passed to the `get` method and `company_id` is present in the selected companies.

If the sequence `company_id` field value is not present in the user currently visible companies, it will return an empty list and the `_next` method will return `False` because `seq_ids` is empty.

```py
def _next(self, cr, uid, seq_ids, context=None):
    if not seq_ids:
        return False
```

***Include the user allowed companies in the search result:***

The res company search method was altered to make it possible to return the user company and all his allowed companies by passing the `user_preference` throw the context.

You can find a comment in `res.company` [_search](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7.0/openerp/addons/base/res/res_company.py#L188) method that highlights that:

```py
if context.get('user_preference'):
    # We browse as superuser. Otherwise, the user would be able to
    # select only the currently visible companies (according to rules,
    # which are probably to allow to see the child companies) even if
    # she belongs to some other companies.
    user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, uid, context=context)
    cmp_ids = list(set([user.company_id.id] + [cmp.id for cmp in user.company_ids]))
    return cmp_ids
```

*example*:

```py
if context is None:
    context = {}
context["user_preference"] = True
self.pool.get("ir.sequence").get(cr, uid, 'ir.attachment', context=context)
```

***Alternative to store attachments in the server file system:***

To store files in the OpenERP server filesystem, you can install the document management system.

[Managing Attachments](https://doc.odoo.com/book/7/7_19_Documents/7_19_Documents_attachment/#managing-attachments) documentation of `OpenERP-7`

> If you do not install the document management system then the files that are attached to an OpenERP resource are stored directly in the database. **Once the document management system has been installed, the contents of the files are no longer stored in the database but are stored instead on the OpenERP server filesystem in a directory named 'filestore'**.

You can then read and add attachments to OpenERP resources quite independent of the OpenERP interface or the FTP server using simple drag and drop.